# Selenium - Cant interact with web driver

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to load a specific chrome profile using Python selenium webdriver, but i  cant interact with the driver after assigning the chrome profile. it opens the chrome profile that i wanted, but from there - nothing. i cant do any action. for example - im trying  to open Microsoft.com:

This works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.microsoft.com')
```

**But this doesnt work at all:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/'+username+'/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/'+username+'/Documents/selProject/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.microsoft.com')
```

The above code opens chrome, but doesnt go to microsoft.com or any other action.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you have Chrome open already with that user signed in.

In order to use chrome with that profile, while also running the script you'll need to separate the directories where the profiles are pulled from. That is, move (or copy) the `Default` profile to another directory that you call to within the `user-data-dir` argument.

Comment: You are right my firend. i has to put `taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe 
in the cmd, then it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do following things and check whether it works.
Upgrade python bindings using

```
pip install -U selenium
```

for chrome browser download the latest chrome driver "ChromeDriver 2.45"
form http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and write the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("Path of the Chromedriver" + "chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('http://www.microsoft.com')
```

Comment: thank you but its not it. i've managed to get chrome to open, and to make it work in the normal way, but when i try launching the chrome profile - the chrome window comes up with the right profile but none of commands like 
'driver.get('http://www.microsoft.com')' works.